# ggvis::export_png on Windows

Tags: r, ggvis

Similar to [Getting ggvis::export_png() working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999741/getting-ggvisexport-png-working) but I'm trying to get this working in RStudio on Windows.

I've installed node.js and downloaded vega and added ./bin to my PATH, but I get the error

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_points() %>% export_png
Writing to file plot.png
Error in vega_file(vis, file = file, type = "png") : 
  Conversion program vg2pngnot found.
```